# Anyone knows how to create an attribute of a Class which will be a '''set''' of all instances of that class?

Tags: python, class, object, constructor, set

I know that each instance will inherit that attribute, but I want a **function** or should I call it a **method** of that class to return the set of all instances created of that class.

So let's say I created 3 instances and call a method from the last one that will return all the previously created instances as well as the one that I am calling it from.

I was able to achieve it by making a list, but would it be possible to return a set?

Is there some kind of constructor that I am missing for it?

```
class Bee():
    
    instances = []

    def __init__(self, name, identifier):
        self.name = name
        self.identifier = identifier
        

    def __str__(self):
        self.instances.append(f"{self.identifier} {self.name}")
        return f"{self.identifier} {self.name}"

    def get_hive(self):
        return self.instances
```

Comment: You really don't want to add the instance to the list each time `__str__` is called. Add the instance in `__init__`.

Comment: First you need to define when two instances are considered to be equal

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would create `Hive` as a separate class and put the `Bees` inside. You then have a clear and explicit data structure whose job includes keeping track of all Bees created.

Something like:

```
class Hive:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bees = []

    def add_bee(self, bee):
        self.bees.append(bee)


class Bee:
    def __init__(self, name, identifier):
        self.name = name
        self.identifier = identifier

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Bee({self.name}, {self.identifier})"

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)


# User code example
hive = Hive()

b1 = Bee('My Bee', 0)
b2 = Bee('Some Other Bee', 1)

hive.add_bee(b1)
hive.add_bee(b2)

print(hive.bees)  # display all bees inside the hive
```